# Interview task: check if array consists of pairs in O(n) time and O(1) of additional memory

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Here is one example of task that I was asked on the interview which I believe was either misspelled or improperly defined but maybe I'm wrong, so here goes:

It is required to provide an implementation of function which checks that the argument array consists of duplicates only, as an example there were two arrays provided:

```
var x = [11,12,11,12]; // True, array consists of duplicates
var y = [66, 3278, 12, 12]; // False, 66 and 3278 contain no pair
```

The problem is in constraints the algorithm should perform this check in O(n) time, with O(1) memory space

What do you think, is it possible, because I don't see a way that can happen...

Comment: Put another way, you need to ensure the frequency of each unique value is an even number.  How do you compute *that* in O(n)?

Comment: That was my question :) Seems impossible right? Or maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: I agree that O(1) memory is going to make this tricky...

Comment: It may help to XOR the elements, this will always be 0 if it consists entirely of duplicates, but it goes wrong sometimes (e.g. 1,2,3 would XOR to 0)

Comment: That's a working approach (at least somehow) And that's a triangle rule, due to xor being associative the same way as ordinary +

Answer (score 6):

Impossibility results are much harder to come by than algorithms, so it's frustrating to have an apparently unsolvable problem like this.

Certainly there's no one-pass algorithm, by a communication complexity argument over the midpoint of the input. With (e.g.) only k words of storage, remembering the precise multiset from the first k+1 items is impossible, so we can follow those items with another k+1 that cause an incorrect output.

On the flip side, there's a probabilistic algorithm that succeeds most of the time. Compute the XOR of a pseudorandom function applied to each input element, and return that the elements are paired if and only if the XOR is 0. As Peter observes in the comments, **it is insufficient to let the pseudorandom function be the identity**, due to inputs like {0, 1, 2, 3}. The point of the PRF is to bring the properties of linear algebra over Z/2 to bear such that the probability of getting a spurious zero is equal to the probability that a random word is zero, which, for a long word, is quite small.

Comment: Assuming uniformly distributed input (and a good PRF), this reduces the probability of false positive from 2^-n to 2^-m (where n is the original word-size, and m is the new word-size), I believe?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth We don't need a particular input distribution, just an oblivious adversary. Yes, this algorithm can be amplified by changing the size of the PRF output.

Comment: I've contacted guys that were asking this question they say there are two conditions xor is just one part...

Comment: @Lu4 The other part is you passing on a company that asks ridiculous interview questions like this.

Comment: Actually the questions that were asked were really professional and extraordinary complex at the same time, this one was one of the last questions, probably asked to kick the hat of top my head

Comment: It's not a ridiculous but a very good interview question. When answering such a question, a scientist says "impossible", and an engineer says "I'll do it with a small probability of error". You want to hire the engineer.

Answer (score 2):

- Start with 1.
- For every number x, from the array, multiply by the x'th prime number.
- If the result is a square number, the array only contained duplicates. (or maybe a few quadruples, or other multipele twins)

Comment: The product is much too big to pretend that this runs in O(n) time

Comment: @Lu4 If bignums are OK, then just XOR `1 << x` and skip the whole prime number thing.

Comment: You need O(1) space (but possibly with *very large* word size), and O(N) time (plus a bit extra for the sqrt ;-)

Comment: @DavidEisenstat That probably doesn't meet the O(1) space complexity but at least the space requirement doesn't depend on the size of the array

Comment: @DavidEisenstat - That's really equivalent to a bucket sort!  O(1) space wrt the array size, but O(2^n) space wrt to the word size.

Comment: @joop, O(1) space with very large word size that depends on N is NOT O(1) space

Comment: @MattTimmermans I don't think there's any reason to believe that the magnitude of the numbers depends on the amount of numbers in this problem.  There could be very many repetitions of small numbers or a small amount of large numbers.

Comment: @GuyGreer, even if it was full of 1s it would take O(N) space to hold the product, which would be 2^N

Comment: Well, any construction until now is either not collision free (such as @DavidEisenstat's Zobrist hashing variant), or it needs a lot of memory for a bitmask or a product,

Comment: @MattTimmermans Did you mean full of 2's? I see your point though.

Comment: What's the (2^60)th prime, please remind me, I seem to have misplaced my table of primes.

Answer (score 1):

David gives a practical solution that always runs in O(n) time and almost always produces the correct answer.

You should probably accept David's answer, but for the record:

A solution that always produces the correct answer but runs in *expected* linear time would be to incrementally convert the array into an open addressed hash table, removing duplicates as you discover them.

There are a couple tricks required to do this incrementally, which I won't expand because this is not really the most practical answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the problem is a little bit under-specified. What is the type of elements in your array? Is there any distribution the input is coming from (perhaps all elements come from a 'small' set or a 'small' interval, so that you can apply some countsort-like approach or some other trivial one)? I would have asked all these. They are very important aspects when you face a problem involving complexity theory notions. If you do not know these details, it is not really clear what `O(1)` means in the first place.

But since all of them have no answer, I assume that you needed to provide a general-purpose solution. It is however extremely plausible that each element in your array can be represented with a finite constant number of bits (say `L` bits). Assuming this, since `L` is a constant, 2<sup>L</sup> is a constant too, thus, a solution which allocates 2<sup>L</sup> bits fulfills the `O(1)` memory constraint. You can now opt for a solution that sets and resets bit entries in the above mentioned bitmap while iterating through your input array.

It is not plausible your interviewer was looking for something like this, but it is a perfectly valid answer from a complexity theory point of view, and I would have provided it as a first solution during the interview. However, I agree that, depending on the relation between 2<sup>L</sup> and `n` and on their magnitude, this approach might lead to highly inefficient implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Since numbers have fixed lengths in practice, any radix-based approach would technically give a O(N) running time, O(1) memory complexity. Floats can be treated as ints if necessary (it's not clear if strings are allowed though).

Now, radix sort normally needs a secondary array to store the digit-sorted numbers, but sorting can also be done in place by "recursive swapping", i.e. we take a number from cell i and we have to put it into cell j, so we replace the number in cell j with it, then do the same for j, repeating until we return back to cell i. It does need an extra bit to mark the cells that have already been processed though. In practice you should be able to use some of the higher bits, but if the interviewer is a jerk and doesn't allow it, I'd just use a single pass with a full 2^32 radix, which technically is still O(1). This recursive swapping is not a stable sort however, so you won't be able to use LSD sort, but MSD sort with recursion should still work. Of course, for the last digit you don't have to do any actual sorting and can just check if the counts in all buckets are even.

Obviously, this approach begs the question if the original array can be modified at all. If not, I doubt any non-probabilistic solution is possible.